# How to convert base64 decoding from python2 to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I am working on a script that downloads and processes subtitle files. Files come in gzip, and the documentation says: use: gzinflate(substr(base64_decode($subs_b64_data_from_xmlrpc),10)).
In Python 2 this works fine, and I end up with a str that contains the subtitle text.

```
compressed_data = download_data['data'][0]['data'].decode('base64')
sub_text = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(compressed_data)).read()
print(sub_text)
```

Gives me this str:

```
841
01:52:28,344 --> 01:52:29,878
Sweet dreams, angel.

842
01:53:44,844 --> 01:53:46,377
I love you, honey.
```

As I work with python 3 I changed .decode('base64') to base64.b64decode() as per the python 3 documentation.

```
compressed_data = base64.b64decode(download_data['data'][0]['data'])
sub_text = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(compressed_data)).read()
print(sub_text)
```

But now my data ends up as a bytes object and the printed data looks like this:

```
00:33:30,009\r\ncalled Babies I\r\nDon\'t Care About.\r\n\r\n694\r\n00:33:31,305 --> 00:34:31,557\r\n
```

How can I do this properly in python3 so I end up with a str as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sub_text is in bytes, you should try this...

```
print(sub_text.decode('utf-8'))
```